# VS 2019: Compilation time of a Xamarin.Forms solution too long?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, compilation

I have a very simple C# Xamarin.Forms solution with three projects: the domain project, the Android and iOS projects. Whenever I make a smallest change in the domain code, the total compilation time can take some 45 seconds or so. The domain dll is compiled in a couple of seconds, the rest of the time goes to compile the Android dll.

Is this normal or should it be faster? If so, what settings control the compilation speed?

Environment: Windows 10.0.18363,
Hardware: i7 CPU (4 cores, 8 logical processors), 2.80 GHz, RAM 32 GB.
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.8.6.
Xamarin: 16.8.000.262
Xamarin.Android SDK: 11.1.0.26

Comment: the total time just 45 seconds, I think it is no problem, because need some time to do some preparation to deploy on android device or emulator.

Comment: Thanks @Cherry Bu-MSFT. But if I compare it with my big desktop solution with dozens of projects and which compiles in a few seconds... I wanted to learn other people's experience.

Comment: Maybe you can use **Dex compiler: dx,Linking:  Link SDK Assemblies** to reduce app size for android.